# Why is DNSServiceProcessResult calling my callback twice?

Tags: c++, qt, bonjour

I've built the [Qt+Bonjour integration demo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html) from Qt Quarterly, but one thing I can't wrap my head around is that a single call to `DNSServiceProcessResult()` is calling the `DNSServiceResolveReply` callback function twice.

It should be calling it once! What I mean is, this single line:

```
DNSServiceErrorType err = DNSServiceProcessResult(dnssref);
```

Results in the `DNSServiceResolveReply` callback I passed to `DNSServiceResolve` to be called twice.

The `interfaceIndex` is different - first time it is `10000010`, second time it is `20`, but I have no idea what that means.

All other parameters are the same between calls (except `flags`, of course, which is `kDNSServiceFlagsMoreComing` the first time and `0` the second).

---

**Edit**

This is how I call the `DNSServiceResolve` function.

```
DNSServiceErrorType err = DNSServiceResolve(&dnssref, 0, 0,
                                            record.serviceName.toUtf8().constData(),
                                            record.registeredType.toUtf8().constData(),
                                            record.replyDomain.toUtf8().constData(),
                                            (DNSServiceResolveReply)bonjourResolveReply, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was that I was passing `0` for the `interfaceIndex` when calling `DNSServiceResolve`.

The docs say that:

> If this resolve call is
>                    as a result of a currently active DNSServiceBrowse() operation, then the
>                     interfaceIndex should be the index reported in the DNSServiceBrowseReply
>                     callback.  If this resolve call is using information previously saved
>                      (e.g. in a preference file) for later use, then use interfaceIndex 0, because
>                      the desired service may now be reachable via a different physical interface.